# Metro app with FTDI-USB driver

Tags: c#, windows, microsoft-metro, driver

(Note: the following question is about a Intel based full Windows 8 tablet for which the drivers work perfectly for regular Windows Desktop (i. e.  non-Metro) applications.)

For Metro applications,  there's the generic WinUSB support,  but I'm unsure what is needed to use the widely used FTDI driver and f2dx.dll user space handler.  Due to the fact that the FTDI chips don't support direct endpoint based communication,  but instead impose some additional custom protocol,  I cannot simply use the endpoint based WinUSB driver.  Would switching to the CDC mode of FTDI work with Metro (essentially,  this causes the device to appear as a serial port) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that there's now an official guide from FTDI regarding this topic: [WinRT Guide](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCQQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.ftdichip.com%2FSupport%2FDocuments%2FInstallGuides%2FAN_271%2520D2xx%2520WinRT%2520Guide.pdf&ei=LallVdzhOsj-ywPVw4HYBA&usg=AFQjCNF8gesBWDqOiswm2XT6srk2YJ1oeA&sig2=Q-nCPPISSSpj5etzVqgF6A&bvm=bv.93990622,d.bGQ)

Answer (score 1):

[This question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/84725/usb-to-serial-converter-using-the-cdc-acm-specification) under electronics seems to say that switching to CDC mode with your FTDI device is not an option, as the CDC mode is not true CDC, but rather a CDC-like implementation.

Unfortunately, I don't have a suggestion yet on what should work - looking into the exact same thing myself.

Comment: There's now an official guide from FTDI regarding this topic. See my answer to my question ...